# are there any methods to decode str in python? AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

I need to decode text in file

from
b'I know what you feel mba mba seperjuangan \xf0\x9f\x98\x90'

to
'b I know what you feel mba mba seperjuangan '

but i got
'b I know what you feel mba mba seperjuangan xf xf x x'

I tried to decode the the but I got an error
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

````
tok = WordPunctTokenizer()
pat1 = r'@[A-Za-z0-9]+'
pat2 = r'https?://[A-Za-z0-9./]+'
combined_pat = r'|'.join((pat1, pat2))
def tweet_cleaner(tweet):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tweet)
    souped = soup.get_text()
    stripped = re.sub(combined_pat, '', souped)
    clean = stripped.decode("utf-8","strict").replace(u"\ufffd", "?")
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", clean)
    lower_case = letters_only.lower()
    # During the letters_only process two lines above, it has created unnecessay white spaces,
    # I will tokenize and join together to remove unneccessary white spaces
    words = tok.tokenize(lower_case)
    return (" ".join(words)).strip()
testing = df.tweet[:100]
test_result = []
for t in testing:
    test_result.append(tweet_cleaner(t))
test_result```
````

Comment: I think decode is a method for encode strings. To check this, assign a random string to a variable "b" than type dir(b) and then dir(b.encode()). You will see that decode is a method available only for encode b

Answer (score 2):

Strings are already decoded. you cannot decode them again.

You can only encode them.

In fact strings are a sequence of unicode letters.

and byte strings is a sequence of bytes.

bytes can be decoded into strings.
strings can be encoded into bytes.

If you get a string from beautifulsoup, then it did already some decoding of the bytes or it was already fed with a string.

Perhaps you can give a very small example string / html file to explain your exact issue.

And we can try to solve your concrete problem.

Comment: is there any methods to revome this emoticon code \xf0\x9f\x98\x90?

Comment: what is weird is, that what you show here looks more like contents of a byte string.

Could you perhaps create a very small tweet and add two print statements to your code.

1st print `print( "Tweet = %r" % tweet)` before the line `soup = BeautifulSoup(tweet)`
and after the  line `souped = soup.get_text()`  add the 2nd print  `print("Souped = %r" % souped)`

This should help us to reproduce the issue